# Python 'progress' module doesn't show spinner from os.fork() within function

Tags: python-3.x, function, fork, progress

I would like to use the [progress](https://pypi.org/project/progress/) module, however, it seems that the spinner doesn't work inside os.fork() within a function. For example:

```py
import sys, time, signal, os
from progress.spinner import MoonSpinner


def spinner_func():
    spinner = MoonSpinner('this is a test')
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            spinner.next()
        exit()

    # Some long-running, blocking action would normally go here
    time.sleep(20)

    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    spinner.finish()
    print('Done!!')
```

This same code works *outside* a function, in that it shows the spinner until the end of execution. I'm not sure how to use this module inside a function, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the 'spinner' variable must be assigned inside the child process, and it can be sent to parent process through multiprocessing.Queue()

For example:

```py
import sys, time, signal, os, multiprocessing
from progress.spinner import MoonSpinner


def spinner_func():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        spinner = MoonSpinner('this is a test') # <<--notify
        q.put(spinner)
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            spinner.next()
        exit()

    time.sleep(20)
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    spinner = q.get()
    spinner.finish()
    print('Done!!')

spinner_func()
```